# 'Calculate' variables as fields in the Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I have a simple model:

```
class Atividade(models.Model):
    valor_brl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    dolar_ref = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    valor_usd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
```

I create after a method to calculate a new value using the two fields from the model

```
@property
def valor_usd_novo(self):
    valor_usd_novo = self.valor_brl / self.dolar_ref
    return valor_usd_novo
```

If I call `{{ valor_usd_novo }}` I get the result I want.

After this I create the save() method, to save `valor_usd_novo` result in `valor_usd` field from the model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.valor_usd = self.valor_usd_novo()
    super(Atividade, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The point is that when I call `valor_usd` I got no results and the database do not update with the result from `valor_usd_novo` method.

What I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`valod_usd_novo` is a `property`, so you need treat it like an attribute, not a method. Hence, drop the call and refer as an attribute:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.valor_usd = self.valor_usd_novo  # not self.valod_usd_novo()
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. I already tried this but got no results too. The field `valor_usd` remains with no values in the DB and if I call `{{ atividade.valor_usd }}` I still got no results.

Comment: @ViniciusCruvinel Check if you get the other field values correctly as it gets it's value from `self.valor_brl / self.dolar_ref`.

Comment: Yes. When I call `{{ atividade.valor_usd_novo }}` (from `def valor_usd_novo(self):`) in my template I got the right result/value from the division. When I override the save() method and call `{{ atividade.valor_usd }}` I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate all the help. I found the solution for the problem:

```
def new_value(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.valor_usd = self.valor_usd_novo
    super(Atividade, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return self.valor_usd
```

With this code when I call `{{atividade.new_value}}` in the template I got the new value and the value in `self.valor_usd` update.